# Scrape from website using VBA, but it doesnt work. What to do?

Tags: excel, vba, extract

I have this website:
http://ga.healthinspections.us/georgia/search.cfm?start=21&1=1&f=s&r=ANY&s=&inspectionType=Food&sd=03/26/2016&ed=04/25/2016&useDate=NO&county=Fulton&

And I have already wrote the code, but even first page doesnt work. My goal is extract following establishment details as example from every page:

```
Column 1: 103 West Lounge (Food Service Inspections)
Column 2: 103 WEST PACES FERRY RD ATLANTA, GA 30318
(Skip this detail) View inspections:
Column 3: July 10, 2012 Score: 92, Grade: A 
Column 4): July 26, 2013 Score: 90, Grade: A 
Column 5): February 19, 2014 Score: 98, Grade: A 
Column 6): December 12, 2014 Score: 100, Grade: A 
Column 6): November 13, 2015 Score: 99, Grade: A
```

Currently the code extract only URL from nowhere without any details and need to review what to change or is wrong:

```
Sub Test()
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Dim link As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set IE = New InternetExplorer

' Test 2 pages (page 2 and page 3) starting from page 2. So far so good.
For i = 2 To 4 Step 2

myurl = "http://ga.healthinspections.us/georgia/search.cfm?start=" & i & "1&1=1&f=s&r=ANY&s=&inspectionType=Food&sd=03/26/2016&ed=04/25/2016&useDate=NO&county=Fulton&"
IE.Visible = False
IE.navigate myurl
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set html = IE.document
' I assume here is the problem, because I need to supplement code part to find these details. 
Set link = html.getElementsByTagName("a")

' This part was intended to test if I can to extract at least one detail.
For m = 1 To 2
For Each myurl In link
Cells(m, 1) = link

Next
Next m
Next i
'Also I tried to test with msgbox but no luck either
'MsgBox link

IE.quit
Set IE = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Maybe something is messed up or I just have a lack of knowledge's. :) Hope to get any help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the references set? for Microsoft Internet Controls and Microsoft HTML Object Library? If so try his in replacement of the section of your code.

```
Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim link As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set IE = New InternetExplorer
```

Comment: Sure I have enabled both Libraries, but no luck. Also changed Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument . Code runs by itself without error, but it extracts URL from somewhere and that is not I am searching. All I know is something doesnt extract because of Set link = html.getElementsByTagName("a") or somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the innertext using the method below.

```
Sub DumpData()

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = True

URL = "http://ga.healthinspections.us/georgia/search.cfm?start=1&1=1&f=s&r=ANY&s=&inspectionType=Food&sd=03/26/2016&ed=04/25/2016&useDate=NO&county=Fulton&"

'Wait for site to fully load
IE.Navigate2 URL
Do While IE.Busy = True
   DoEvents
Loop

RowCount = 1

With Sheets("Sheet1")
   .Cells.ClearContents
   RowCount = 1
   For Each itm In IE.Document.all
      .Range("A" & RowCount) = itm.tagName
      .Range("B" & RowCount) = itm.ID
      .Range("C" & RowCount) = itm.className
      .Range("D" & RowCount) = Left(itm.innerText, 1024)

      RowCount = RowCount + 1
   Next itm
End With
End Sub
```

I got that from a great guy whose name is Joel.  He is a wiz with this stuff.

Once your data is imported into your sheet, do some simple cleaning, to get rid of the superfluous stuff and you should be all set.

Comment: Hi. Thank you Joel and you. Its nice at least there is something, but I wont do manual cleaning for 893 pages. There is too big mess. :)